# Accessing an Image on my site from local

Tags: javascript, php, xml, cors

So I have folder on my desktop which i created a basic html file inside which calls an image from my site. Here is a piece of the code which suppose to load the image.

```
window.img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.onload = start;
img.src = "http://carlitosworks.com/ferrari_cyan.png";
```

But I keep getting this error which says

> Access to Image at 'http://carlitosworks.com/ferrari_cyan.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

So I read a bit about the CORS policy and created file called crossdomain.xml which has this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This crossdomain.xml file is located in the root where the image is also located. I threw in the wildcard * as a last resort and nothing.

The code does not load up the image. Can somebody point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a question tag for the server you use to host WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo -

```
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

should rather be

```
img.crossorigin = "anonymous";
```

> note the small "o"

tried on my local. it's working .